# Large API call with no pagination

Tags: json, wordpress, api, php-curl

I need to retrieve data from an API source that has a massive amount of entries. (1800+) The problem is that the source has no pagination or way to group the entries. We are then saving the entries as post on the site and will run through a Cronjob daily.

Using curl_init() to retrieve the data from the API source. But the we keep getting a 503 error, timing out. When it works it retrieves the data as json saving important info with as metadata and the rest as json.

Is there a more reliable way to retrieve the data. On other sites I have worked on we have been able to programmatically run through an API per page in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try saving the JSON to a file first, then running the post creation on the JSON in the file vs. the direct cURL connection. I ran into similar issues in the past, even with an API that had pagination.